# AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, yolo

I am working on `Yolo3-4-PY` to implement it with `Tkinter`.

I've looked everywhere but have not been able to resolve the issue.

When I run the program, the canvas is displayed, but when I click on Start `Video(**btton**)`, I get the following error:

```
Loading weights from weights/yolov3.weights...Done!
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py:119: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  if mode not in ["1", "L", "RGB", "RGBA"]:

    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
    File "webcam_demo.py", line 13, in start_video
    show_frame()
    File "webcam_demo.py", line 39, in show_frame
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=cv2image)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 120, in 
    __init__
    mode = Image.getmodebase(mode)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 313, in 
    getmodebase
    return ImageMode.getmode(mode).basemode
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PIL/ImageMode.py", line 55, in 
    getmode
    return _modes[mode]
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
    Exception ignored in: <bound method PhotoImage.__del__ of 
    <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x7f4b73f455c0>>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 130, in 
    __del__    name = self.__photo.name
    AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

Comment: In my case, I got this error when Python could not find the image file at the path I had put. I corrected the path and it started working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Issue

In the line  `imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=cv2image)`, you are passing a numpy array (cv2image) as input to ImageTk.PhotoImage. But the source code of PIL.ImageTk mentions that it requires a PIL image.

This is what source code of [PIL.ImageTk](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/ImageTk.py#L87) mentions for **init**() of PhotoImage.

```
class PhotoImage(object):
    .....
    :param image: Either a PIL image, or a mode string.  If a mode string is
              used, a size must also be given.
```

## Solution

So basically, you will have to convert the numpy array to a PIL Image and then pass it to ImageTk.PhotoImage().

**So, can you replace the line `imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=cv2image)` with `imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=PIL.Image.fromarray(cv2image))`?**

This would convert the numpy array to a PIL Image and it would be passed into the method.

## References

I extracted the code for converting a numpy array to PIL Image from [this source](https://codeyarns.com/2014/01/16/how-to-convert-between-numpy-array-and-pil-image/).

Answer (score 11):

in my case , correct with just simply add this line

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
```

complete code :

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
image = PIL.Image.open(r"C:\Users\Hamid\Desktop\asdasd\2.jpeg")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
l = Label(image=img)
l.pack()
```

Comment: This worked for me, too. What was specifically happening for me was that, because a root `Tk()` instance couldn't be found, this exception was being raised: `RuntimeError(f"Too early to {what}: no default root window")`, which seems to be raised whenever one tries to initialize a `PhotoImage` object without having a `Tk()` instance.

Comment: Same problem here. Good solution!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.... there's apparently a nasty side-effect in Tkinter which can cause this.

Note (from hamidjahandideh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63645287/851699) ) that it matters that you create your root window BEFORE cresting the ImageTk.

ie. this fails with `AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'`

```
im_numpy = cv2.imread(ResourcePhotos.BLUE_PERSON_TRAIL_PHOTO)[:, :, ::-1].copy()  # Load BGR Image
im_pil = Image.fromarray(im_numpy)
imagetk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im_pil)
window = tk.Tk()  # This line must come BEFORE crearting ImageTk
tk.Label(window, image=imagetk).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

But this works:

```
im_numpy = cv2.imread(ResourcePhotos.BLUE_PERSON_TRAIL_PHOTO)[:, :, ::-1].copy()  # Load BGR Image
im_pil = Image.fromarray(im_numpy)
window = tk.Tk()  # This line must come BEFORE creating ImageTk
imagetk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im_pil)
tk.Label(window, image=imagetk).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

when you place the image variable in the label , you must initiate the image variable to "image".

Eg: (CORRECT APPROACH)

```
photo = PhotoImage(file = "C://Users//Carl//Downloads//download.png")
label1 = Label(image = photo)
label1.pack()
```

Eg : (WRONG APPROACH)

```
photo = PhotoImage(file = "C://Users//Carl//Downloads//download.png")
label1 = Label(photo)
label1.pack()
```