# Python Application cannot find Image(.png) file at Runtime

Tags: python, image, runtime, exe, pyinstaller

So I built this python application with a tkinter GUI. I used pyinstaller to convert the .py file into an executable (.exe) file, so that I can send it to non-technical people to use.

When I run the code with these two lines commented out...

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("DOJ Pricing Analyzer")
root.resizable(False,False)
#canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 350, height = 500, bg = 'white') <-----------This line commented out
#image = ImageTk.PhotoImage( file = "matrix.png" )<--------------This line commented out
canvas1.create_image(0, 0, image = image, anchor = NW)
canvas1.create_text(185,75,fill="white",font="Impact 15 ",
```

The application runs perfectly when executed (in .exe form in Windows), except the main window is a blank white canvas.

The problem is I need the app to utilize matrix.png so that the UI actually looks cool and not boring.

So after hours of research I tried playing around with the .spec file in many different ways. I thought this would do the trick....(I simply added the matrix.png file to datas), then ran pyinstaller DOJPriceAnalyzer.py --onefile from Powershell

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['DOJPriceAnalyzer.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\CV7617\\Desktop\\program'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:\\Users\\CV7617\\Desktop\\program\matrix.png','.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='DOJPriceAnalyzer',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

But after running the .exe it produced, I am left with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DOJPriceAnalyzer.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 89, in __init__
  File "site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 58, in _get_image_from_kw
  File "site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2809, in open
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'matrix.png'
[3080] Failed to execute script DOJPriceAnalyzer
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x0F9F07C8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

I've tried many combinations of things (lost count at this point) including this..(modifying .spec files to these, then going through the same motions of running pyinstaller DOJPriceAnalyzer.py --onefile, then running the .exe file)

```
datas=[(matrix.png','.')],
```

and

```
datas=[('C:\\Users\\CV7617\\Desktop\\program','data')],
```

But these all produce the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662773/attributeerror-photoimage-object-has-no-attribute-photoimage-photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, you are not keeping a **reference** to the image. 
Take a look at [this link for an explanation](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm).

To add a permenant reference, just add a line such as

```
canvas1.im = image
```

The [`canvas.create_image` docs](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method) do mention this

"The image object. This should be a PhotoImage or BitmapImage, or a compatible object (such as the PIL PhotoImage). **The application must keep a reference to the image object**", but is easy to overlook that!

I don't think this is a specific Pyinstaller issue either. Your approach of adding the image to the `datas` in the spec file was correct, and that should work OK.

```
datas = [('matrix.png','.')]
```

I tried to reproduce your case, with the snippet of code you provided, and I was able to replicate the error and then fix it with this method, so hopefully this will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

tried all options but converted exe file will run in the same computer but when ported to another it fails by saying no png/ico/gif files. when copied all these files along with exe file to another computer's same directory everything works smoothly..